# Joining three tables not returning data

Tags: sql, join

I know I am missing something and I have done my research, but its just not coming to me, so I thought I'd post my problem.

I have three tables (`Jobs`, `Persons`, and `Orgs`). The Jobs table has an `org_surveyed_by_id` and `person_requestor_id`. They are foreign keys, i.e., they are equal to the values of the `Orgs.Org_id` and the `Persons.Person_id`, respectively.

I am trying to link these three table together and grab information from the persons table and the organizations table. I am able to join one, but when I join the second, I get no results.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT sj.JOB_NUMBER, sj.TITLe, sj.JOB_CATEGORY, 
       sj.PURPOSE, sj.ORG_SURVEYED_BY_ID, 
       sj.PERSON_REQUESTOR_ID, os.org_full_name
FROM SURVEY_JOBS sj
    JOIN organizations os ON sj.org_surveyed_by_id = os.org_id
    JOIN persons ps ON sj.person_requestor_id = ps.person_id
WHERE SURVEY_JOB_ID = :P30_SURVEY_JOB_ID
```

The second join is giving me problems.

Comment: are you sure the data is populated so that you would get results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `JOIN` seems fine, so probably there is no data on the `persons` table, or `person_requestor_id` on the `SURVEY_JOBS` table is `NULL`. Try using `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT  sj.JOB_NUMBER, 
        sj.TITLe, 
        sj.JOB_CATEGORY, 
        sj.PURPOSE, 
        sj.ORG_SURVEYED_BY_ID, 
        sj.PERSON_REQUESTOR_ID, 
        os.org_full_name,
        ps.SomeColumnHere
FROM SURVEY_JOBS sj
LEFT JOIN ORGANIZATIONS os 
    ON sj.org_surveyed_by_id = os.org_id
LEFT JOIN PERSONS ps 
    ON sj.person_requestor_id = ps.person_id
WHERE sj.SURVEY_JOB_ID = :P30_SURVEY_JOB_ID
```

You should still get results, and if the `JOIN` condition for the `PERSONS` table isn't met, you'll see `NULL` values for the columns of that table.

Comment: wow.....that worked perfectly, all because of left join insetad of join. Those are the kind of prbolems I hate....they drive me crazy, but thanks for your help